# how to have vscode autocomplete axios

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

in vscode when typing, `axios.`, I would expect `get` autocomplete.

I see autocomplete of the following instead

```
axios
fetchData
response
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get();
};
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think you can get auto completion on your IDE if using only cdn. I think you require to have a package, types or something installed locally.